# Can not get PUT to work in ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, put

I get 405 error for PUT action in ASP.NET WebApi.

I read tons of pages, most of them suggest to remove the WebDAVModule module and WebDAV handler. For example: http://forums.iis.net/t/1166025.aspx

So I end up with this:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

However, now I get error code 500.

If I'm using only this:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

I still get 405.

Been wasting my whole day on this. What am I missing?
(IIS 7.5)

Comment: I had too many problems with the `WebApi` that I could not solve after trying everything. So I scrapped the idea and went on to use a `Web Service`. Works like magic and less stressful.

Comment: ME TOO! I read somewhere else on Stack overflow that microsoft said you have to disable WebDAV at the site level. Click on your web site, click on the `WebDAV Authoring Rules` feature, then on the side panel, click `Disable WebDAV`. I had to do this in addition to removing the handler and module. I hate this solution though, I wish there was something at the web application level.. Sorry I cant find the link to this solution...

Comment: Try my solution mentioned [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53341203/268584)

Answer (score 1):

I'm having same issue with PUT method. The solution is Custom CORS policy providers.

The [**EnableCors**] attribute implements the **ICorsPolicyProvider** interface. You can provide your own implementation by creating a class that derives from Attribute and implements **ICorsPolicyProvider**.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyCorsPolicyProvider : Attribute, ICorsPolicyProvider 
{
    private CorsPolicy _policy;

    public MyCorsPolicyProvider()
    {
        // Create a CORS policy.
        _policy = new CorsPolicy
        {
            AllowAnyMethod = true,
            AllowAnyHeader = true
        };

        // Add allowed origins.
        _policy.Origins.Add("http://myclient.azurewebsites.net");
        _policy.Origins.Add("http://www.contoso.com");
    }

    public Task<CorsPolicy> GetCorsPolicyAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(_policy);
    }
}
```

Now you can apply the attribute any place that you would put [**EnableCors**].

```
[MyCorsPolicy]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    .. //
```

For example, a custom CORS policy provider could read the settings from a configuration file.

As an alternative to using attributes, you can register an **ICorsPolicyProviderFactory** object that creates **ICorsPolicyProvider** objects.

```
public class CorsPolicyFactory : ICorsPolicyProviderFactory
{
    ICorsPolicyProvider _provider = new MyCorsPolicyProvider();

    public ICorsPolicyProvider GetCorsPolicyProvider(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return _provider;
    }
}
```

To set the **ICorsPolicyProviderFactory**, call the **SetCorsPolicyProviderFactory** extension method at startup, as follows:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetCorsPolicyProviderFactory(new CorsPolicyFactory());
        config.EnableCors();

        // ...
    }
}
```

It should work, But after your deployment if it will not work then Please add the below configuration in your web.config

```
<system.webServer>    
  <modules>    
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />    
  </modules>    
  <handlers>    
    <remove name="WebDAV" /> 
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />  
    <add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />   
  </handlers>    
</system.webServer>
```

After deployment just do **IISRESET** or restart **App pool**

Thank you